# Mapping Firebase Auth users to Firestore Documents

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, user-management, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use **Firebase**'s `Firestore` database to handle `User`s in my Android app.

Initially I want to use the **id** returned from the `Auth` package (a string), and set that as the id for the `users` `Collection` in the database. When creating a `Document` inside of the `Collection` `users`, I set a `uid` field to that auth package string.

I realize there is no way of setting that string to an indexable value so that queries like:

```
// get Auth package uid string
db.collection("users").document(auth_uid_string);
```

would work.

So the alternative, I guess, is to use `Query.whereEqualTo("uid", auth_uid_string)` which would give me the user in a list, because firestore doesn't assume the query is for a unique value.

I want to avoid the above solution, and devise a way to store the `users` of the app in `firestore`, and use the `auth` package to verify that I fetch the correct user. Is such a solution possible? Or should I try a *different* firebase service, or even just run a postgres server in heroku or something?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I am not sure how to do this in android, but with JS I am doing the following:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(currentUser.uid).set(currentUser)
```

`currentUser` is the user object that the authentication function returns (I use `signInWithCredential`)
It is working perfectly. I am sure you can implement a similar approach in android.

Comment: Yeah, so i can set the index with `set`. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best way to do it as Firebase explicitly says:  // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project.
  // Do NOT use this value to authenticate with your backend server,
  // if you have one. Use getTokenWithCompletion:completion: instead.

Comment: @JoseTapizquent That's for _authenticating with your backend server_, as what the comment _explicitly_ mentions. It's fine to use the user's ID for declaring documents.

Comment: I'm not sure this still works.  I don't think `currentUser` is serializable.  I get `FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Data must be an object, but it was: a custom Q object`