# String value of userid of firebase auth to document firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Can you help in my Android project. I am trying to get the the currentUID in firebase auth and I want it to show the string value in the document of my firestore.

```
db2.collection("Assessment").document(??).set(answer);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mapping Firebase Auth users to Firestore Documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46622291/mapping-firebase-auth-users-to-firestore-documents)

Answer (score 1):

The currently logged-in user's ID can be retrieved via the [`getUid`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#getUid()) method of a [`FirebaseUser`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html) instance, which can be retrieved via [`FirebaseAuth#getCurrentUser`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#getCurrentUser()):

Java:

```java
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
String uid = user.getUid();
// Or alternatively, a one-liner (although the code complexity is higher)
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

Kotlin:

```
val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
val user = auth.currentUser // Note: This returns a nullable class
val uid = user?.uid
// Or alternatively, a one-liner (although the code complexity is higher)
val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
```